# Запуск minecraft 1.7.10 Forge через bat

Tags: java, bat

Собрался делать кастомный лаунчер для игры `Minecraft`, но она написана на [java](/questions/tagged/java).
С [java](/questions/tagged/java) я толком не знаком.

Пока что я понял, как запускать файл с расширением `.jar`:

```
javaw -jar {имя файла}.jar
```

---

Проблема в том, что у `Minecraft` нет `minecraft.jar`

Есть только  с версиями (например, `1.7.10.jar`)
Если запустить их, а они, как я понял, и являются версиями игры, вылезает ошибка, что не найден класс `net.minecraft.client.main`.

---

В общем, я покопался на ютубе и понял что у всех все работает кроме меня... Как говориться в видеоуроке, надо запустить `minecraft` через `TLauncher`, скопировать команду которую использует `Tlauncher`, подредактировать и потом вставить в батник. У автора все заработало, а у меня что-то вообще никак... Незнаю, можно-ли здесь размещать ссылки на стороннии ресурсы, но если можно, то вот ссылка: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFpsjH7J35c . Возможно будет полезно.

Если это все-таки противоречит правилам, то пожалуйста напишите и я удалю.

Comment: В гугле: лаунчер майнкраф. Первая ссылка) И запускай оттуда

Comment: Так мне надо свой создать..

Comment: Ааааааа. Не вчитывался. Это вообще странно. Вроде всегда джарка была обычная. Но это давно было... Ща не знаю

Comment: Возможно, надо в джарнике покопаться, чтобы понять, что не так. Надо через winrar его открыть.

Comment: в .jar вообще вакханалия твориться... https://prnt.sc/oht5jg

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на джарник. Не знаю как, правда, но я в вас верю.

Comment: СО заполонили лопатостроители)))

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение проблемы! Оказалось что команда которую использует TLauncher не обращает внимания на пробелы, тоесть

```
privet hi == "privet hi"
```

Из - за этого, она не задумываясь выдавала что-то на подобии

```
--version=windows 10
```

Это ломало код и в итоге припятствовало запуску майнкрафта...

---

**Решение** 
 
1) Запустить `TLauncher` и включить консоль, 
2) скопировать команду которую использует `TLauncher`, 
3) убедиться что нету пробелов в самих аргументах (ну если знакомы с бат, то поняли), 
   
4) изменить название папок и файлов версий так чтобы в них небыло пробела (это можно обойти ковычками, но так сложнее и мутерней), 
5) Запустить бат!

Если все сделано правильно и в бате нету пробелов, то он должен не закрыть консоль, а запуск `minecraft` должен начаться.

Comment: Изменять названия папок из-за какой-то команды, когда можно просто написать два символа кавычек? Ну, ваше дело.

Comment: Изменить название одной папки вместо того чтобы искать и подставлять ковычки, как по мне намного более эффективно...

Comment: Ну например, системные папки переименовать нельзя. После переименования других папок тоже могут возникнуть проблемы, если какие-то ещё приложения сохранили у себя путь через эту папку.